# spring boot creating beans from configuration list

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to create a lot of JMS listeners in my Spring boot 3.1 application. Topic names come from configuration like this:

```
    consumers:
      - topic_foo
      - topic_bar
      ...
      - topic_anything
```

How can I create beans in runtime and how can I inject them in my service, because I have to suspend/resume some listeners in my service?

thx,
Zamek

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy. Just iterate to the list of topics and create a new `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` programatically for each. I am assuming you already build a Connection Factory and will have a way to map tour topic name with a specific `MessageListener` where you have implemented your processing logic. So having a `Map<topicName, MessageListener> messageListeners` available you do this:

```
Map<String, MessageListenerContainer> listenerContainers = new HashMap();
messageListeners.forEach(topicName, listener) -> listenersContainers.put(
    topicName, defaultMessageListenerContainer(jmsConfig, listener, topicName));

private DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfig jmsConfig, MessageListener messageListener, String topicName) {
    messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    messageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(jmsConfig.connectionFactory());
    messageListenerContainer.setRecoveryInterval(jmsConfig.getRecoveryInterval());
    messageListenerContainer.setReceiveTimeout(jmsConfig.getReceiveTimeout());
    messageListenerContainer.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    messageListenerContainer.setDestinationName(topicName);
    messageListenerContainer.setConcurrency(jmsConfig.getConcurrentConsumers());
    messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
}
```

Then once you have these containers you can `.initialize() and .start()` or `.stop() and .shutdown()` as you need based on their key in the map.

As for the `beans` part I don't think you really need to have these listeners as Spring beans. Your service can build the above massage `listenerContainers` map part of the service constructor. However if for whichever reason you need them as beans you can just register them as beans using `GenericApplicationContext.registerBean(String beanName, Class<T> beanClass, Supplier<T> supplier, BeanDeffinitionCustomizer... customizers)` method.

Comment: Hi Julian, it works well, thank you.